# Difference between re-index and restart of JIRA server

Tags: jira

After making direct database changes, under what circumstances does one need to re-index JIRA and under what circumstances does JIRA need to be restarted?

I made some direct changes to the JIRA database, but I had to restart the JIRA server before I could see those changes in JIRA. Why did the JIRA re-index not help in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display information to the end user, JIRA draws data from the database directly, from the Lucene index, and from in-memory caches.

Re-indexing JIRA will eliminate any inconsistencies between the Lucene index and the database.

Restarting JIRA will effectively flush all of the internal in-memory caches that it maintains of various objects that are also stored in the database and/or Lucene. A variety of object types are cached, and the specifics can vary from one JIRA release to another, and there is no hard-and-fast rule to determine if something may be stored in an in-memory cache.

If you absolutely must edit things directly in the JIRA database (which is not normally recommended), you will want to both restart JIRA and reindex JIRA again before allowing any users or automations to access the system.